# Info about attached display on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi running the RPI variant of Debian. I need to get info about the display attached to the HDMI port from the command line. I need the name of the display (vendor and model) and optionally other relevant info.

How to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command your looking for is

> /opt/vc/bin/tvservice

If you just type that into terminal, it will show you what options you should pass in.

I'm not sure that it will give you the vendor and model information. But it will give you more information regarding the display that is plugged in.

Hope this helps you.

**UPDATE**: Yeah looked at it now, really dont think the command will give you the vendor and model. But this is about as much information as you'll get from the monitor (From the Raspberry Pi)